# WCF service login and operation permissions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, security

For a WCF service host implementation, I need to roll my own authentication & authorization procedure, but I can't find any information about how WCF supports this. The system should be pretty straight forward using **Username**, **Password** for authentication and **Role** to check for operation permissions.

In WPF documentations and tutorials, all I found is authentication using WinLogon, IIS login or security certificate and permissions using ASP.Net roles and security realms. What I would like to have is (pseudo example):

```
myChannelFactory.Username = "myuser";
myChannelFactory.Password = "mypass";
myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

and for operation contracts

```
[OperationContract(Permission = MySecurityRoles.Administrator)]
public bool Reboot();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities how you could achieve this.

You could use sessions and authenticate in the first call by passing username and password to the server.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188749/WCF-Sessions-Brief-Introduction

Or you could (as you do in the example code) use the existing features and create a custom Username and Password validator on the server.
This example is quite nice:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx

You can then check the role in the actual implementation.

Comment: Isn't it possible to check the role on the interface? I'll implement this contract in many services, I don't intend to repeat my code. :)

Comment: You could consider creating a custom role provider: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13032/Custom-MembershipProvider-and-RoleProvider-Impleme